# If $Z$ is a closed subset of Hilbert Space $X$, is it true that $Z\neq X \implies Z^{\perp}\neq \{0\}$?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, inner-products

It is clear from Projection theorem that if $Z$ is a subspace, then since $X=Z\oplus Z^{\perp}$, $Z^{\perp}$ is not trivial (By the way, is there any reasoning that would show this without referring to Projection theorem? - I feel like using something unnecessarily advanced to show something trivial)

Is the same true for any closed subset of $Z$? I feel like the answer is no, but I can't find an example.

Comment: You can have a closed subset which spans the full space, i.e.,the unit ball. Therefore, you get a counterexample.

Comment: Are you saying that, you can have closed $Z$ and span of $Z$ equals $X$ then $Z^{\perp}=\{0\}$?

Comment: Yeah, because being orthogonal to every vector in $Z$ implies it is orthogonal to every vector in span of $Z$. (By linearity of inner product)

Comment: I see, so even something like $\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ works... that was pretty obvious now that I think about it, thanks!